# Flutter - How to detect key holding (CTRL) during mouse click in the unfocused widget?

Tags: flutter, click, key, mouse

I can identify when CTRL is pressed using focus like `FocusNode`. But for that, the widget needs to be focused first. Does anyone have any tips on how to detect this CTRL when the widget is not focused or when it can't even gain focus?

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: Wrap(
            crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
            spacing: 16,
            children: [
          _button(1),
          _button(2),
          GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => print('Tap!'),
              child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                  child: const Text('Tap with CTRL')))
        ]));
  }

  Widget _button(int number) {
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => print('button $number'),
        child: Text('Button $number'));
  }
}
```

Comment: This may be the answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/71853874/1052581

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```dart
onTap: () {
  if (!RawKeyboard.instance.keysPressed
      .contains(LogicalKeyboardKey.controlLeft)) {
    print('Clicked with Control');
  }
}
```

In my experiment with Linux Desktop app, any of the two Ctrl keys make both `LogicalKeyboardKey.controlLeft` and `LogicalKeyboardKey.controlRight` present in the set. Notably, just `LogicalKeyboardKey.control` is never found in the set.